# Opencart Check if address is empty

Tags: php, opencart

I managed to remove the necessary address requirement fields when registering in opencart (no address info is required at this step). But I've left the address as a requirement to the checkout as guest process. (i think this make it seem easier when registering)

But since the address is needed when checking out for delivery if you are logged in I want Opencart to query and find out if the address is blank, if so it should by default select the enter new address option in step 2.

Please help with solutions on how to do this.

Comment: You may check the `address` table with the logged-in user's `customer_id`.

Comment: Hi Sankar V, do you mind explaining a bit better in detail

Comment: write a query to get the addresses of the logged-in user from `address` table with the logged-in user's `customer_id in` `where` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really used open cart, but you should be able to build into the checkout process a quick check to see if the address is valid. For example, first check if the user is logged in:

```
if($this->customer->isLogged())
{

}
```

You can then use the `if` to check for the address for example:

```
if($this->customer->isLogged())
{
   $customer = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE id = '" . $this->customer->id . "'");

   if(!$customer->address)
   {
       //Customer needs to add address -  show address form
   }
   else
   {
       //Customer is logged in and has address - happy shopping
   }
}
```

Please see here the [Open Cart Database Structure](http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=&media=database_schema_oc1541_product.png) although I do not believe this to be complete.

Like I say I have not used Open Cart, but the above should get you started at least. You will need to check the database table and check for example the field is called `address` and not say `address_1`, this code for example would need to be changed if that was the case.

```
$customer->address
```

Changed to

```
$customer->address_1
```

I am also not sure if queries return objects or arrays so similarly the following:

```
$customer->address_1
```

Would need to be changed to

```
$customer['address_1']
```

You just need to test the following an debug from there.

Comment: Opencart already route the login user and guest shopper differently. THough I do get the logic behind your answer. It is to say if Address one is empty then  enter new address and a radio button would be selected.